# How to draw vertices in a vertex buffer in another color

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, vertex-buffer

I'm using Direct3D 9 to draw lines.

The vertices I am using now have the format `D3DFVF_XYZ|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE` and are stored in a vertex buffer. They are drawn with `DrawPrimitive` as `D3DPT_LINELIST`.

How do I change the drawn color of a the whole drawn vertex buffer or even a specific vertex without locking the vertex buffer to modify it's content? This has to be done every frame.

Is this possible with a vertex buffer? I would prefer a solution without a custom shader (using the default direct3d 9 pipeline).

If this is not possible, what would be the next best thing to do performance wise? I can only think of locking the vertex buffer or using `DrawPrimitiveUP`. Both are pretty terrible performance wise.

---

Updated with solution code:

```
m_pDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
m_pDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
m_pDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CONSTANT);
m_pDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_CONSTANT);
m_pDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_CONSTANT, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(120,0,255,0));
```

The vertices don't need `FVF_DIFFUSE` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the fixed function pipeline you could use `SetTextureStageState` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to specify a constant color, which should be used with `D3DTSS_CONSTANT` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). With this option you could set a color for the whole drawcall.