# How can I fill a 3D mesh created with D3DXCreateText?

Tags: directx, direct3d

First, I would like to thank all the users that mantain Stack Overflow, this is an awesome resource for every software developer.

I'm using DirectShow + DirectX 9 these days for a project, and I'm trying to show text in 3D using the D3DXCreateText() method. This method gives me a mesh, which I can easily transform using world transformations as I need, and show it with the DrawSubset() method:

```
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HFONT font = CreateFont(0,0,0,0,FW_NORMAL,false,false,false,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH|FF_DONTCARE,"Calibri");
SelectObject(hdc, font);

ID3DXMesh *mesh;
D3DXCreateText(d3dDevice,hdc,"Hello World",0.001f,0.0f,&mesh,NULL,NULL);

--------------------- Now inside beginScene()

...
D3DXMATRIX translation;
D3DXMATRIX scaling;
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation,0,0,1);
D3DXMatrixScaling(&scaling,-0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);
d3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(translation * scaling));

mesh->DrawSubset(0);
...
```

All seems to be fine, but I have a problem: I don't know how to fill this mesh to a simple color. I've read many examples, and I even have used the 3D Text example that came with the DirectX 9 SDK (they use a D3DMATERIAL9 to fill it), but it doesn't work.

Being more specific, if I only fill this text on screen, it appears bright white (I can't change its color, but at least it's white). And if I render a quad with a texture (which I'm using to show frames captured from a camera with DirectShow), then the text shows like it's using this texture too!:

```
...
d3dDevice->SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(SCREENVERTEX));
d3dDevice->SetTexture(0, texture);
// World transformations for this VertexBuffer in here
d3dDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
...
```

Could you, please, help me with this?

P.S.: I know there's a way to use the dxDrawText() method with D3DXVec3Project() to achieve similar results, but I need a real 3D text with depth.

**--------------------------------------------------
Solution for anyone interested
--------------------------------------------------**

On the one hand and as @NicoSchertler advised, I should set to null the texture after painting it with the DrawPrimitive() function:

```
d3dDevice->SetTexture(0, NULL);
```

This only shows the text, but you can't paint the mesh even using the SetMaterial() method showed in the SDK examples. So, @Gnietschow answered with a way to fill it:

```
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CONSTANT);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_CONSTANT);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_CONSTANT, /* D3DCOLOR HERE */);
```

And this works! But, keep in mind, that you have to reset each property defined with the SetTextureStageState() method before painting again another texture (if you don't do this, you will maintain the color defined earlier for the text). This is done with this ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
```

Hope this helps to anyone and again thank you guys for your help :).

Comment: Can you add the code that applies the material? If you have applied a texture before, you have to reset it (set texture to null). Do you have any lighting?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @NicoSchertler. If I set the texture to null, then the text appears in white but I still can't change its color.

Hmmmm... No, I have lighting disabled as (I think) I don't need it for my purpose.

I'll edit to add the code requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one color you could set it via the texture stages (same way as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448206/how-to-draw-vertices-in-a-vertex-buffer-in-another-color)):

```
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CONSTANT);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_CONSTANT);
d3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_CONSTANT, /* YOUR COLOR */);
```

If you need complex coloring or texturing of your text, you must convert the fvf of the mesh an fill it with appropiate data. `D3DXCreateText` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) only create a mesh with positions and normals, but without any colors and texture-coordinates.

Comment: Thank you @Gnietschow for your quick answer too. This seems to work, but it also changes the color of my texture. Is there a way after calling the DrawPrimitive() method (draws the vertex buffer associated with the texture) to say "Ok, now clear everything and draw a different thing"?

Comment: The only way ist to revert all changes you've made. The device has a specific state, which can only be changed, but neither saved nor loaded in one single step.

Comment: Hmmmm... No, excuse me, I tried to ask that there should be a way to draw two different objects with different colours and textures, right? Anyway, in your original reply you talk about converting the FVF of the mesh, did you mean to create a new vertex buffer and copy the vertices manually?

Comment: Yes, you must alter the state of the device between your drawcalls. E.g. first you draw a text in green, therefore set the code above to green. Second you draw another text in red and use the code again to render it red. After that you render your textured object. Therefore you must set the texture stage states to use the texture instead of a constant color. And remind to set an unset your texture before the drawcalls.